# simple switch user c# console application

Tags: c#

I am a beginner at c# and I am learning by writing small programs, this one is an app that stores & retrieves data the user enters.

I want it to handle multiple users

So I am trying to get a simple switch user function set up that stores the previous users information, while allowing someone else to quickly login and make a change.

Here is my code below, it first checks to make sure the program has already run, so once it has left the login function.

```
        while (pbRunning)
        {
            psPrevUser = psUserName;
            piPrevStoreWeek = piWeek;
            piPrevStoreDay = piDay;
            pbRunning = false;
        }

        psUserName = null;
```

I then ask for username

```
        //Validates user input
        while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(psUserName))
        {
            Console.Write("Please Enter the name of the account you wish to edit: ");
            psUserName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

I then check to see if psUserName == psPrevUser & if it does I call the menu

```
if(psUserName == psPrevUser)
        {
            piDay = piPrevStoreDay;
            piWeek = piPrevStoreWeek;
            psPrevUser = null;

            Menu(ref piChoice, ref psUserName, ref psName, ref piMinutes, ref psSport, ref piDay, ref piWeek, ref piPrevStoreDay, ref piPrevStoreWeek, ref psPrevUser, ref piTimeArray, piAverage, ref piArraySize, ref piNum, ref piNumItems, ref pdHeight, ref pdWeight, ref pdBMI, ref piBMIWeek, ref piBMIOnce, ref pbRunning);
        }
```

else it just runs normal logon code

my problem is, when I change user and the select change user in the menu, it overwrites the psPrevUser.

E.g If I logged on as Dave, then wanted to change user to John to make a quick change to Johns account, then change back to Dave, without needing to go though login again I cannot as as soon as John logs in it overwrites psPrevUser.

I have tried numerous different ways to save the usernames, but it is always over written.

I have tried debugging with breakpoints to see what is happening, but I just cannot see where the error is occurring.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to make this work correctly?

EDIT: Here is the full function for people wanting all the code

```
        static void Login(ref int piChoice, ref string psUserName, ref string psName, ref int piMinutes, ref string psSport, ref int piDay, ref int piWeek, ref int piPrevStoreDay, ref int piPrevStoreWeek, ref string psPrevUser, ref int [] piTimeArray, int piArraySize, ref int piAverage, ref int piNum, ref int piNumItems, ref double pdHeight, ref double pdWeight, ref double pdBMI, ref int piBMIWeek, ref int piBMIOnce, ref bool pbRunning)
    {
        //This checks to see if program is running
        while (pbRunning)
        {
            psPrevUser = psUserName;
            piPrevStoreWeek = piWeek;
            piPrevStoreDay = piDay;
            pbRunning = false;
        }

        psUserName = null;

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("                      User Login");
        Console.WriteLine("********************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //Validates user input
        while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(psUserName))
        {
            Console.Write("Please Enter the name of the account you wish to edit: ");
            psUserName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //if username and prevuser are the same, just load straight into the menu
        if(psUserName == psPrevUser)
        {
            piDay = piPrevStoreDay;
            piWeek = piPrevStoreWeek;
            psPrevUser = null;

            Menu(ref piChoice, ref psUserName, ref psName, ref piMinutes, ref psSport, ref piDay, ref piWeek, ref piPrevStoreDay, ref piPrevStoreWeek, ref psPrevUser, ref piTimeArray, piAverage, ref piArraySize, ref piNum, ref piNumItems, ref pdHeight, ref pdWeight, ref pdBMI, ref piBMIWeek, ref piBMIOnce, ref pbRunning);
        }

        //Lable for error message to, reload the question
        Here:

        //Validates user input
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Please Enter week number, you wish to start from: ");
        while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out piWeek))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("***ERROR*** YOU MUST ENTER A NUMBER ***ERROR***");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please Enter week number, you wish to start from: ");
        }

        //Validates user input
        if (piWeek < 1 || piWeek > 52)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("***ERROR*** PLEASE ENTER NUMBER BETWEEN 1 & 52 ***ERROR***");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Write("Press any key to try again.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            goto Here;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        if (File.Exists(psUserName + piWeek + ".txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();

            //Validates user input
            Console.Write("Please Enter day number, you wish to start from: ");
            while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out piDay))
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("***ERROR*** YOU MUST ENTER A NUMBER ***ERROR***");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Please Enter day number, you wish to start from: ");
            }
        }

        //Validates user input
        if (piDay < 1 || piDay > 7)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("***ERROR*** PLEASE ENTER NUMBER BETWEEN 1 & 7 ***ERROR***");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Write("Please Enter day number, you wish to start from: ");
            while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out piDay))
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("***ERROR*** YOU MUST ENTER A NUMBER ***ERROR***");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Please Enter day number, you wish to start from: ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        //If a file does not exist it will create it, stating from week 1
        else if (!File.Exists(psUserName + piWeek + ".txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome an account is being created for you");

            //This will create a files for new user
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(psUserName + "1" + ".txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Name: " + psUserName);
                sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
                sw.WriteLine("Time spent execising in minutes");
                sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
                sw.WriteLine();
                sw.WriteLine("Week - 1");
                sw.WriteLine();

                //creates a sepereate file so I can ready times into the array easier
                using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(psUserName + "1" + "Times.txt", true))
                {
                    sw.Write("");
                }
            }
        }

        pbRunning = true;

    }
```

Comment: You have to do login/logout for every user perhaps.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might be the case, I was trying to find a simple work around using variables. But it seems, that it is not possible. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Provide complete code, then...

Comment: It certainly is possible though. But I'm not quite understanding your code. If the first block is executed after you made a normal logon, then this is your point of mistake.

Comment: I have added the complete code for the login function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using

```
 //Validates user input
while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(psUserName))
{
            Console.Write("Please Enter the name of the account you wish to edit: ");
            psUserName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Instead you should use input like [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-readline)

```
class Program
{
    string someUserName;

    static void Main()
    {
    while (true) // Loop indefinitely
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter input:"); // Prompt
        string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from user
        if (line == "exit") // Check string
        {
            break;
        }
        Console.Write("You typed "); // Report output
        Console.Write(line.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(" character(s)");


        if(someUserName != line)
        {
           // New username has been detected
           someUserName = line;
           // Do extra stuff
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference to the initial problem, but you're right. a main loop is better (Though the author might used it without saying so)

Comment: I am using that for validation to avoid Exceptions, as I don't know how to use try & catch yet. I am also using a main loop, that reports the output, but I have login as separate function, with the variables passed by reference, see above I added the complete function

Comment: @Chris Try to split you big chunk of code to more readable functions. It will help you to see the entire algorithm better. Good luck!